# How to organize components?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have a `Product` component that represents data about product.

Near information is placed component `Buttons` with two buttons that allow to add product to favourit list and to wish list (`FavouriteComponent`, `WishComponent`).

My template representation is:

```
<app-product>
   <app-buttons></app-buttons
</app-product>
```

Where to place components `FavouriteComponent, WishComponent`, inside `<app-product>` or inside `<app-buttons>`?

Where to write handler for button? Inside `ButtonComponent` or upper in parent component?

Could you explain me how to make right decicion?

Comment: what is inside app-buttons?

Comment: Inside buttons is button HTML with click.

Comment: So you will have 3 buttons in total? 1 in app-buttons and 2 that you want to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template representation looks wrong.
it should just be
`<app-product></app-product>`
and then in your App Product components html file you'll have whatever html you want in there plus your `<app-buttons></app-buttons>` element.
From the description you give you'll probably want the other component elements placed in this file also.
As far as project structure it sounds like you should have something like this from the app-product component:

```
AppProduct
    L AppButtons
    L FavouriteComponent
    L WishComponent
```

This is assuming those 3 components will always be used in AppProduct.
You should also use a service to perform the logic of adding the products to whatever database the Favourite and Wish Components pull from.

Comment: Do you mean all compnent should be placed in one leven relative parent? But why FavouriteComponent is not inside Button, because ButtonCompnent is initializer, where FavouriteComponent it is dialog window with form to fill for save.

Comment: I'm sorry, without a better description I don't understand what your vision for the app is.
The "buttons" are in the product component right? and the favorite and wish components are both separate from the product and button right? Separate as in, in a different part of the application?